# Confidence interval for sigma in a purely fixed effect model

Tags: r, lm, lme4

Is there a standard way to estimate confidence interval for the variance parameter of a linear model with fixed-effect. E.g. given:

```
reg=lm(formula = 100/mpg ~ disp + hp + wt + am, data = mtcars)
```

how can I get the confidence interval for the variance parameter. *confint* only details fixed effect and *lmer* from *lme4* does not accept model without level-2 random-effect, which is my case here.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to implement it yourself.
Like so :

```
reg <- lm(formula = 100/mpg ~ disp + hp + wt + am, data = mtcars)

alpha <- 0.05
n <- length(resid(reg))
sigma <- summary(reg)$sigma

sigma*n/qchisq(1-alpha/2, df = n-2) ; sigma*n/qchisq(alpha/2, df = n-2)

> sigma*n/qchisq(1-alpha/2, df = n-2) ; sigma*n/qchisq(alpha/2, df = n-2)
[1] 0.4600539
[1] 1.287194
```

It comes from the relation :

[image: $\frac{n \hat \sigma^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-2}$]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for the `summary()` function.

The code shows the following:

```
data(mtcars)
reg<-lm(formula = 100/mpg ~ disp + hp + wt + am, data = mtcars)
summary(reg)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = 100/mpg ~ disp + hp + wt + am, data = mtcars)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -1.6923 -0.3901  0.0579  0.3649  1.2608 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept) 0.740648   0.738594   1.003  0.32487   
# disp        0.002703   0.002715   0.996  0.32832   
# hp          0.005275   0.003253   1.621  0.11657   
# wt          1.001303   0.302761   3.307  0.00267 **
#   am          0.155815   0.375515   0.415  0.68147   
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.6754 on 27 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.8527,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8309 
# F-statistic: 39.08 on 4 and 27 DF,  p-value: 7.369e-11
```

To select it, you can store the summary as a variable and select the coefficients.

```
summa<-summary(reg)
summa$coefficients
```

With that, one can select the sd covariate that you want and do the confidence interval with the % of interest. To learn the confidence interval, one can read how it is done [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/confidence-interval.html)

R does it automatically using `confint(object, parms, level)`

In your case, `confint(reg, level = 0.95)`

Comment: Thanks however I can't see how in your example you get some confidence interval on the *variance* parameter. Did I miss something in your post?

Comment: What do you mean then by the variance parameter ?. I am not sure what are you making reference to.